# Printing the number of days in a given month and year [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, calendar, days

I've been trying to work out a way to accomplish what's in the title, without using any imported calendar/datetime libs from Python. There's little function at the top for checking whether or not the year is a leap year, which I want to be able to reference when printing the number of days in a given February, however I'm not too sure how to do so. (I've guessed with something like output. bla bla)

So far I've come up with something like this, which should make clear what I want to do, but I'm still a bit new to Python, so I would love a few tips/help on fixing up my code for the task.

```
# A function to determine if a year is a leap year.
# Do not change this function.
def is_leap_year (year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

# You should complete the definition of this function:

 def days_in_month(month, year):

    if month == 'September' or month == 'April' or month == 'June' or month == 'November'
    print 30

    elseif month == 'January' or month == 'March' or month == 'May' or month== 'July' or month == 'August' or month == 'October'\
    or month== 'December'
     print 31

    elseif month == 'February' and output.is_leap_year = True
    print 29

    elseif month == 'February' and output.is_leap_year = False
    print 28

    else print 'Blank'
```

Ok I've fixed up my code, and it seems to output the correct data for every month but February:

```
# A function to determine if a year is a leap year.
# Do not change this function.
def is_leap_year (year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

# You should complete the definition of this function:

def days_in_month(month, year):

    if month in ['September', 'April', 'June', 'November']:
        print 30

    elif month in ['January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August','October','December']:
        print 31        

    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year == True:
        print 29

    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year == False:
        print 28
```

Any hints to fix up outputting for February?

EDIT: Just needed to add the argument year when referencing the first function. Here is the 100% working code for future reference:

```
# A function to determine if a year is a leap year.
# Do not change this function.
def is_leap_year(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

# You should complete the definition of this function:

def days_in_month(month, year):

    if month in ['September', 'April', 'June', 'November']:
        print 30

    elif month in ['January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August','October','December']:
        print 31        

    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == True:
        print 29

    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == False:
        print 28

    else:
        return None
```

​

​

​

Comment: `elseif` should be `elif`

Comment: Righto, fixed that up. Also, this is the error code I'm getting upon running the code, but I'm guessing there will be more to come once this one is sorted:    def days_in_month(month, year):
                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level        ....the ^ should be on the colon, just not sure how to format this comment.

Comment: You could shorten it a little by writing `if month in ('September', 'April', 'June', 'November'):`, and since it's in a function, you might want to `return` the value computed rather than `print` it.

Comment: I shortened it up a little and fixed a few things, mind checking out my second batch of code in the O.P ? Can't seem to get February analyses to work..

Comment: function `is_leap_year` need argument `year`, you missed it

Comment: Ah, beauty, all fixed. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some syntax error in your code:

1. There should be no space before `def days_in_month(month,year)`. Python use indentation to separate code blocks. This is the error you given in comment.
2. There is no `elseif` in python, it should be `elif`
3. `output.is_leap_year = True`,  it should be `is_leap_year(year) == True`. The `False` part should be changed too.
4. after `if` statement and `else` there should be a `:`, like

   ```
   if month == 'September' or month == 'April' or month == 'June' or month == 'November':
       print 30
   elif month == 'January' or month == 'March' or month == 'May' or month== 'July' or month == 'August' or month == 'October' or month== 'December':
       print 31
   elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == True:
       print 29
   elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == False:
       print 28
   else:
       print 'Blank'
   ```

Comment: Okay I fixed up all those, appreciate the help. Now I'm getting a syntax error returning on line 10, on the quotation mark to the right of the 'November' string, what could be causing that?

Answer (score 4):

A more pythonic approach would be to define the mapping in a dictionary, then simply retrieve the values from the dictionary.

Try it out:

```
days_in_month_dict = {"January": 31, "February": 28, 
                      "March": 31, "April": 30,
                      "May": 31, "June": 30, 
                      "July": 31, "August": 31,
                      "September": 30, "October": 31,
                      "November": 30, "December": 31}

def is_leap_year(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

def days_in_month(year, month):
    if is_leap_year(year) and month == "February":
        return 28

    try: 
        #attempt to get value from dictionary 
        return days_in_month_dict[month]
    except KeyError:
        #key does not exist, so we caught the error
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Takes the year and month as input and returns the no. of days
"""
def is_leap_year (year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

def days_in_month(month, year):
    if month == 'September' or month == 'April' or month == 'June' or month == 'November':
        result=30
    elif month == 'January' or month == 'March' or month == 'May' or month== 'July' or month == 'August' or month == 'October'or month== 'December':
        result=31

    elif month == 'February' and output.is_leap_year ==True:
        result=29

    elif month == 'February' and output.is_leap_year == False:
        result=28
    return result

print(is_leap_year(2016))
print(days_in_month('September',2016))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
month = int (input ('month (1-12): '))

if month < 13:
    if month == 2:
        year = int (input ('year: '))
        if year % 4 == 0:
            if year % 100 == 0:
                if year % 400 == 0:
                    print ('29')
                else:
                    print ('28')
            else:
                print ('29')
        else:
            print ('28')

    elif month >= 8:
        if month % 2 == 0:
            print ('31')
        else:
            print ('30')

    elif month % 2 == 0:
        print ('30')
    else:
        print ('31')

else:
    print ('Only 1-12 accepted')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26242691)

Answer (score 0):

```
month=input("month")
year=int(input("year"))
if year%4==0:
        year=('leap year')
if month in ['September', 'April', 'June', 'November']:
        print ("30")

elif month in ['January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August','October','December']:
        print ("31")        

elif month == 'February' and year == "leap year":
        print ("29")

elif month == 'February' and  year != "leap year":
        print ("28")

else:
    print("none")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

*# Write a function that determines how many days there are in a particular month.

## Your function will have two parameters: The month as an integer between 1 and 12,

## and the year as a four digit integer.

## Ensure that your function reports the correct number of days in February for leap years.*

```
def year():
  a = int(input("insert your year"))
  def month():
    z = int(input("enter month 1-12 "))
    if z==9 or z==4 or z ==6 or z==11:
      return print(30)
    elif z==1 or z==3 or z==5 or z==7 or z==10 or z==12:
      return print(31)
    elif z ==2 and a % 4==0:
      return print("29 its a leap year")
    elif z ==2 and a % 4==1:
      return print(28)   
    
  month()
year()
```